# Eclipse: Select text a column-based block via shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, iar

I am looking for a shortcut in eclipse to select which I have already used in IAR Embedded Workbench but I didn't find it in Eclipse.

briefly shortcut explained in Iar's doc and looks like in the gif below:

> To select text, press Shift and the corresponding command for moving
> the insertion point. In addition, this command is available:
>
> A column-based block: **Shift + Alt + Arrow key**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Alt-Shift-A` to start block selection. Then use `Shift+arrows` to select an aligned column as in your example. Once you use `Alt-Shift-A` again, the selection mode goes back to normal.

Comment: Thank you. it almost works for me but when I made to tab space, the whole line moving together, not just the right side of the cursor. are there any solutions?

Comment: Looks like the Tab in Block mode always works as a line indent from the start. [This issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288430) seems not resolved. However, pasting a Tab character from the clipboard works for me.